# Restrict Amadeus flight-offers to a specific airline

Tags: r, amadeus

I am using the Amadeus flight-offers API to get basic information about fares. Using URL_OK below I successfully get:

```
A tibble: 30 x 8
   origin dest  total_fares base_fares tax_and_fees dep_date   return_date airline_codes
   <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>        
 1 YYZ    LHR          626.        175         451. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  FI           
 2 YYZ    LHR          626.        175         451. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  FI           
 3 YYZ    LHR          626.        175         451. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  FI           
 4 YYZ    LHR          626.        175         451. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  FI           
 5 YYZ    LHR          711.          1         710. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AC           
 6 YYZ    LHR          719.          1         718. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AC           
 7 YYZ    LHR          727.          1         726. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AC           
 8 YYZ    LHR          727.          1         726. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AC           
 9 YYZ    LHR          728.          2         726. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AY           
10 YYZ    LHR          728.          2         726. 2022-01-10 2022-01-17  AY
```

Now suppose I wish to restrict the search to only a specific airline. If I try the same URL with the addition of `&includedAirlineCodes=FI` (URL_FAIL) nothing gets returned.

Why is this? How do I do a fare search that only includes a specific airline or airlines?

Link to what I believe is the relevant documentation:

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

```
library("tidyverse")
library("httr")
library("rjson")

amadeus_api_key_prod <- Sys.getenv("AMADEUS_API_KEY") 
amadeus_api_secret_prod <- Sys.getenv("AMADEUS_SECRET") 

# Initialize variables
tmp_origin <- NULL
tmp_dest <- NULL
tmp_avg_total_fare <- NULL

# Get Token
response <- POST("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
                 add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
                 body = list(
                   "grant_type"     = "client_credentials",
                   "client_id"      = amadeus_api_key_prod,
                   "client_secret"  = amadeus_api_secret_prod),
                 encode = "form")
response
rsp_content <- content(response, as = "parsed", type = "application/json")
access_token <- paste0("Bearer ", rsp_content$access_token)

# URL_OK
url <-   "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=YYZ&destinationLocationCode=LHR&departureDate=2022-01-10&returnDate=2022-01-17&max=10&adults=1&nonStop=true&travelClass=ECONOMY&max=1&currencyCode=CAD"

# URL_Fail
url <- "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=YYZ&destinationLocationCode=LHR&departureDate=2022-01-10&returnDate=2022-01-17&max=10&adults=1&nonStop=true&travelClass=ECONOMY&max=1&currencyCode=CAD&includedAirlineCodes=FI"


# Get flight info
response <- GET(url,
                add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            "Authorization" = access_token),
                encode = "form")

response
rsp_content <- content(response, as = "parsed", type = "application/json")
rsp_content
```

Comment: I ran both API calls. With the URL_OK there are flights returned but none with the airline "FI". All the flights are with "AC," "AY", "BA" and "LH" airlines. Since the airline FI doesn't appear in the results of the URL_OK, it doesn't appear either in the results of URL_FAIL as the results should be a subset of the first.